# Deliver php mails to special-character-email adresses, such as äüö

Tags: php, email, special-characters

I am using paypal API and I need to deliver php emails to recipients that have email adresses with special characters. All works fine as long as I don't send emails to ü@example.com, ö@example.com and so on...but since 2012 those characters exist in email addresses and I can't get php to understand these charakters right. Somebody can help me???

```
    <?php
    $message = "Bla"
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

    $email_from = 'office@rhythm-one.com'; 
    address
    $email_subject = '=?UTF-8?
    B?'.base64_encode('Bestellbestätigung').'?='; 
    $email_body = "$message";

    $to = $_POST['payer_email'];//<== This could contain ä,ü or ö
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: office@rhythm-one.com \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: office@rhythm-one.com \r\n";
    //Send the email!
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode it to utf8

```
$to = utf8_encode($_POST['payer_email'];
```